# join results into new table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can successfully join two tables, but i'm trying to output the results of the join into a new table.

The following throws a syntax error, but works if the "into" line is omitted.
To be clear - not having problems w/ the join, but the "into" statement.

```
 SELECT evictions.uniqueid_neighborhoods.id, evictions.uniqueid_neighborhoods.neighbor_1, 
evictions.sanfrancisco_evictions_backup2.Breach,
evictions.sanfrancisco_evictions_backup2.NonPayment,
evictions.sanfrancisco_evictions_backup2.Nuisance,
evictions.sanfrancisco_evictions_backup2.IllegalUse
** This causes code to fail 
into evictions_by_commArea 
from evictions.uniqueid_neighborhoods
inner join evictions.sanfrancisco_evictions_backup2 on evictions.uniqueid_neighborhoods.id = evictions.sanfrancisco_evictions_backup2.id
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL uses `CREATE TABLE AS`:

```
CREATE TABLE evictions_by_commArea as
    SELECT un.id, un.neighbor_1, 
           sfe.Breach,
           sfe.NonPayment,
           sfe.Nuisance,
           sfe.IllegalUse
    from evictions.uniqueid_neighborhoods un join
         evictions.sanfrancisco_evictions_backup2 sfe
         on un.id = sfe.id;
```

I also introduced able aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.